# TS2322: Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type '{}'

Tags: angular, firebase

I searched various article in the mentioned question but could not really find an usable answer in the topic...

I have a 'product' object in my app. This is related to a webshop app, which is using an older version of Angular and in that case in the "product-form.component.ts" has this code:

```
export class ProductFormComponent implements OnInit {
   categories$;
   product: {};
```

If I declare it such a way I got this error:

[image]

And of course during ng serve:

[image]

How can I fix it?
Thanks in advance!

Additional info:
Angular CLI: 11.2.13
Node: 14.17.0
OS: darwin x64

Comment: What if you try `product: any;` or `product: object;` ?

Comment: product: object; -> not works, of course 'product: any' was my first idea, and naturally type error gone away but then when I ng serve the app, in the browser console I have this error: "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined at Object.updateDirectives".

Comment: 1. I think you should create an interface `Product` to have the right type. 2. Maybe try to make nullable your value like : `your_property?.title` ?

Comment: It’s a good idea to include code, errors and and structures as *text*, not links and images. That way, if they are needed in an answer, they can be copied and pasted. Also, images are not searchable so future readers maybe unable to locate the question. Take a look at [No Images Please](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Somehow it happened that `product: any;` solved the problem.